# How come this postgres query is working?

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '$1 DAY';
```

I am not getting why this query is working. There is invalid $ literal in the query.

Comment: This works too `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '!%^&$1 DAY'`

Comment: Looks like there is some bug in Postgres query validator :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing `timestamp` or `interval` values, PostgreSQL ignores printable characters that are not `+`, `-`, `.`, a digit or an alphabetic character.

See `ParseDateTime` in `src/backend/utils/adt/datetime.c`:

```c
/* ignore other punctuation but use as delimiter */
else if (ispunct((unsigned char) *cp))
{
    cp++;
    continue;
}
```

From `man ispunct`:

```
ispunct()
      checks for any printable character which is not a space or an
      alphanumeric character.
```

Comment: I was trying to find it in docs and could not. It seems undocumented?.. And obviously from users feedback not intuitive :)

Comment: The details of the input functions are not in the documentation. For things like that, the source is the best documentation.

Comment: Its pretty restrictive: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT